# what regular expression mechanism to match "ski" but not "water ski"?

Tags: regex

What regular expression mechanism can be used to match "ski" but not "water ski"?

Or, match "ski" but not "ski sale"?

Could a short explanation be included?

**Update:** i mean, for example, it should be able to match "2009 ski competition" but not "2009 water ski competition".

Comment: What words should and should not match?  You don't want "ski sale" but why is "ski competition" be ok?  What is your exclusion criteria?

Comment: it is just an example.  suppose i want to find all strings in a document that has the word ski but i know i am not interested in "ski sale".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the updated part, you need to use negative look-behind. Something like

```
(?<!water\s*)(ski\b)
```

That should match the word ski, where water is not the previous word.

EDIT:  I tweaked the regex above, and I meant negative look-behind, not back-referencing.  For ski and ski competition but but not ski sale, you need negative look-ahead.  E.g.:

```
(\bski)(?!\s*sale)
```

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for some more explanation.

Comment: Most regex engines that support lookbehind do not support variable length lookbehind, so the \s* is unlikely to work.

Comment: It works on .NET.  See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html .  If the OP wants answers for a specific engine, he should say so.

Comment: Most regex engines that support lookbehind DO support variable length lookbehind - once there is an obvious maximum width. So a workaround to \s* is to use \s{0,100} instead (or just increase the 100 to whatever is a safe value).

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a multi pass search first remove all instances of water ski and ski sale from the string then do the IsMatch on that. In C# it would look like this.

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
line = Regex.Replace(line, "water ski", "");
line = Regex.Replace("ski sale", "");
bool matchFound = line.IsMatch("ski");
```